# Qlikview 12: prevent sheets from being selected

Tags: tabs, qlikview, qlik-expression

I have a range of multilists on a first sheet (I.e. Selection), and a range of other sheets,called databasesheet1, databasesheet2, databasesheet3,  that contain a mix of data pulling from a variety of databases.

The selections made by the user can potentially have data on all of the sheets, or just one.

Based on the attributes selected in the selection sheet, is it possible to hide, or prevent the user from clicking on other sheets where there is no data?

For example, user selects 'customer x' on the selection sheet.  Data is returned on databasesheet1, but not on the other sheets.  I am looking to prevent the user from looking on the databasesheet2 and databasesheet3, as there is no data returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In each sheet you have on the General tab an option Show Sheet, where you can select Conditional and build an expression to define when the sheet will be shown.

An example, you have a List Field for a Customer Name and you want to have a sheet showing Customer Details that will only show when a single customer is selected in the document. You can use the Conditional option with an expression like =Count(CustomerId) = 1 to get this kind of behaviour.